# Eventual failure: kubectl exec fails with "operation not permitted: unkown"

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have some Pods that are running some Python programs.  Initially I'm able to execute simple commands into the Pods.  However after some time (maybe hours?) I start to get the following error:

```
$ kubectl exec -it mypod -- bash
error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "37a9f1042841590e48e1869f8b0ca13e64df02d25458783e74d8e8f2e33ad398": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container pr
ocess: open /dev/pts/0: operation not permitted: unknown
```

If I restart the Pods, then this clears the condition.  However, I'd like to figure out why this happening to avoid having to restart Pods each time.

The Pods are running a simple Python script, and the Python program is still running as normal (`kubectl logs` shows what I expect).

Also, I'm running K3s for Kubernetes across 4 nodes (1 master, 3 workers).  I noticed all Pods running on certain nodes started to experience this issue.  For example, initially I found all Pods running on worker2 and worker3 had this issue (but all Pods on worker1 did not).  Eventually all Pods across all worker nodes start to have this problem.  So it appears to be related to a condition on the node that is preventing `exec` from running.  However restarting the Pods resets the condition.

As far as I can tell, the containers are running fine in containerd.  I can log into the nodes and containerd shows the containers are running, I can check logs, etc...

What else should I check?
Why would the ability to `exec` stop working?  (but containers are still running)

Comment: Which version of containerd are you running? Or maybe more importantly which version of k3s have you deployed? Someone here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43969 had a similar issue, in the comments someone suggested that this was fixed in v1.6.8 of containerd (or avtually in runc). When checking the k3s releases containerd v1.6.8 was shipped in https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/releases/tag/v1.24.7%2Bk3s1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of GitHub issues [one](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43969) or [another](https://github.com/moby/moby/discussions/43960) from the middle of august. They said it was an SELinux issue and fixed in the runc v1.1.4. You should check your runc version and when it is below the mentioned version then update it.

Otherwise, you can disable SELinux when you aren't working in production:

```
setenforce 0
```

or when you want some more sophisticated solution, try this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43969#issuecomment-1217629129

Comment: this is really helpful!  thanks!  i'll check it out... and respond once I verify.

Comment: I found all 4 of my nodes are running runc v.1.14.

Comment: I ended up upgrading k3s - which I'm told will update k8s and all of the tools it uses.  I'm not seeing the issue anymore, so I'm guessing the issue was related to what @kubenetic suggested - a known issue in one of the dep packages.  I'll accept this answer since it led me to try updating those packages.